# Prevent marker from scaling when zoom out

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want a Google Maps marker to be on a fixed size on a certain zoom level, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/4rxqQ/

```
function initialize() {
var map;
var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(38.713107, -90.42984);
var options = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: centerPosition,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], options);

var icon = 'https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_black.png';
var iconBounds = constructBounds(38.713107, -90.42984);
var staticOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(icon, iconBounds);
staticOverlay.setMap(map);
}

function constructBounds(lat, lng){
var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(lat - .03, lng - .025)
var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(lat + .03, lng + .025)
return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But is there a more smooth solution than in above Jsfiddle?

Comment: What is not "smooth" in the above? And what's your definition of "smooth"?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I thought it would be possible to as for example an option in new google.maps.Marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment: Yes, you can solve it with a marker, but there is no 'ready-to-use' option in the MarkerOptions. Instead of this you can add a zoom change listener and set a new scale for the marker icon. Instead of the GroundOverlay

```
var icon = 'https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_black.png';
var iconBounds = constructBounds(38.713107, -90.42984);
var staticOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(icon, iconBounds);
staticOverlay.setMap(map);
```

you would use a Marker

```
var icon = 'https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_black.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
        lat: 38.713107,
        lng: -90.42984
    },
    map: map,
    icon: icon
});
```

Then you just add the zoom change listener and calculate a new size based on the zoom level:

```
//add a zoom change listener, so you can resize the icon based on the zoom level
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    markerWidth = (zoom/9)*20
    markerHeight = (zoom/9)*34

    //set the icon with the new size to the marker
    marker.setIcon({
        url: icon,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(markerWidth, markerHeight)
    });
});
```

Of course you can change the calculation so the icon size changes in a different way. I just created a quick example. I just updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rxqQ/27/).

Comment: The `MarkerImage` class was deprecated in favor of the `Icon` anonymous object a **long** time ago (after v3.10).

Comment: You are right. I just updated the deprecated `MarkerImage` class to `Icon`.